# delay in ajax success not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

here is my ajax

```
           var $this = $(this);
 $.ajax({

      url: "process.php",
      dataType: 'json' ,
        data :{
            method:'POST',
            id :id ,
          img_val : img_val},
         type : 'POST',
       success: function(output_data){
               if (output_data.msg == 'taken'){

        --->        $this.val('Saved !').delay(3000).val('Save') ;


               }               }
         });
```

actually this code marked with `--->` didnt work with delay it displays directly `Save`

if i remove `delay(3000).val('Save')` it display `Saved !`

and what i want is display `Saved !` and then wait 3 seconds and then display `Save` . how can i achieve this ? thnaks

`$this` is button .

Comment: `delay()` is for animations. Read the docs.

Comment: I swear `delay()` has caused more confusion in jQuery than any other feature. This question comes up daily.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[updated]**
use `setTimeout(function(){ /* your code */},3000);`

**update**: if you still want to use the jquery delay write it like this:

```
$('#dd').val('firstVal').delay(2000).queue(function(){$(this).val('SecondVal');}).delay(...;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/WsP3D/)**

and that's because the default queue of 'delay()' is 'fx' which doesn't include val() in it automatically, so you just have to add it to it.

Comment: **.queue()** is amazing! Thanks for your contribution! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
var $this = $(this);
$.ajax({
    url: "process.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        method:'POST',
        id :id,
        img_val : img_val
    },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(output_data) {
        if (output_data.msg == 'taken') {
            $this.val('Saved!');
            setTimeout(function() { $this.val('Save'); }, 3000);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Using **setTimeout( *function*, *time* )** is the best solution.
But if you want to animate the button, you can make it with [jQuery .animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
var $this = $(this);
$this.val("Saved!").animate(
    { opacity: 0.99 }, //transition
    2000, //duration
    function() { //animation complete
        $this.val("Save");
    });
```